# STATE_IDLE_RINGING instead of CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

I'm making an app for recording voice calls. As far I know, phone goes to OFFHOOK once we make a call.

This is what supposed to be happening.
But my app is recording for the very first time I'm making a call. After that, whenever I'm calling, the phone goes on RINGING state. I put a Log.i() statement for all the states so that I may get the phone state every time it changes. Every time I'm making a call, the phone goes on RINGING state.

Here is the code :-

```
public class CallRecorder extends Service{

private MediaRecorder rec;
private boolean recordStarted;
private File file;
//private TelephonyManager manager;
//private StateListener listener;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();


    rec = new MediaRecorder();
    rec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
    rec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    rec.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/TESTRECORD.3gp");
    rec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);


    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    manager.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK==state && rec == null)
            {
                try {
                    Log.i("OUTGOING CALL", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");
                    rec.prepare();
                    //Thread.sleep(500);
                    rec.start();
                    recordStarted = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

            }
            else if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE==state)
            {
                Log.i("OUTGOING CALL", "CALL_STATE_IDLE");
                if(rec!=null)
                {
                    try{
                    rec.stop();
                    rec.reset();
                    rec.release();
                    recordStarted = false;
                    stopSelf();
                    }
                    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        //Log.e("CALL ERROR",e.getMessage());
                    }// ILLEGALSTATEEXCEPTION WHILE THE CALL ENDS AUTOMATICALLY

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("OUTGOING CALL", "CALL_STATE_RINGING");   // 2nd time outgoing


            }

        }
        }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);       // LISTENER REGISTERATION
    Toast.makeText(this, "Calling...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return 0;
}
}
```

Now every time i'm calling, the number of Logs for **"PHONE_STATE_RINGING"** are increasing.

2nd time I made call, it was shown 3times.

3rd time I made call, it was shown 5times.

4nd time I made call, it was shown 7times.

Here's the logcat.

```
12-26 13:53:45.501: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:45.501: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:45.501: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:45.501: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:45.501: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:45.501: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:45.501: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:45.501: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:45.501: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:45.501: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:45.501: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:45.501: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:45.621: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:52.051: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:52.051: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:52.051: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:52.051: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:52.051: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:52.051: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:52.051: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:52.051: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:52.051: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:52.051: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:52.051: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:52.051: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:52.051: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
12-26 13:53:52.071: I/OUTGOING CALL(7614): CALL_STATE_RINGING
```

After every attempt, the **CALL_STATE_IDLE** is shown.

And some random errors like given below are shown

```
stop is called in an invalid state:4
```

Can anyone tell me why & how it is happening?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't unsubscribed from the event so it's all stacking up :) Pretty simple fix!

Here's my onReceive method:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
    mIntent = intent;
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    tm.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

And this is the line I used at the end of my onCallStateChanged event:

```
((TelephonyManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
```

That should solve it!